# what is the best way to deal with SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, project

I am working on my graduation project
It has the same idea as **calories counter** application of **Fatsecret** >> if you know!

- I created the database file using SQLite, I copied it into the asset folder, and then wrote the code as in this link:
  http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
- recently I read a code that only use **openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory)** to deal with the database
  Can I use this in my case, which code is better?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is good basic documentation on how to work with sqllite in android. Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db to get an overview on how to use sqllite in your application. 
Basic idea is to extend http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html class and from there do the rest of CRUD operations on your database.
Also i forgot to mention: preferably avoid using openorcreatedatabase method, recommendation is to keep using sqliteopenhelper instead

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I think I got the idea now.

Comment: I have almost 7000 record in the table that hold the food information,  is it a practical way to create the table through code and add 7000 insert statements?!!

Comment: No, i don't think so. Data can be best added through sql scripts. I am not sure in which form you have your 7000 records stored at the moment, but using a sql script and sqllite client UI, you can load your data into database first.

Comment: as I mention above, first I create the file in sqlite UI, and then I tried to copy it in my application as I read from here [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-), but when I run my application, It creates the database with only one table android_metadata, the other tables didn't exist?

Comment: I see. Going through your code my assumption was that the check you have in your code on whether the database already exists or not will make sure a pre-loaded database does not get created again:            _boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
 
     if(dbExist){
      //do nothing - database already exist
     }else{_
Am i missing something here?

Comment: If you take look at the link, he said at the end _"Now you can create a new instance of this DataBaseHelper class and call the createDataBase() and openDataBase() methods."_, where should I add this instant in the main activity or in the helper class. and excuse me if I bother you ;)

Comment: I solve the problem and now the tables are created but without the data inside. I can insert into them but when I run a query to return the result an error occurred, **"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed"**
"